# PHP make a multidimensional associative array from key names

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative

Even if it's documented, I need help to better understand this code (only references). I already checked tutorials, but they didn't help me.

```
// initialize variables
$val = 'it works !';
$arr = [];

// Get the keys we want to assign
$keys = [ 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_4' ];

// Get a reference to where we start
$curr = &$arr;

// Loops over keys
foreach($keys as $key) {
   // get the reference for this key
   $curr = &$curr[$key];
}

// Assign the value to our last reference
$curr = $val;

// visualize the output, so we know its right
var_dump($arr);
echo "<hr><pre>\$arr : "; print_r($arr);
```

(Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31103901/4741362  @Derokorian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain it for you to understand it a little better, see the working code [here](https://tehplayground.com/KKAv0byZyiF0CIiD). I hope it helps you understand this `$curr = &$curr[$key];` line. `$curr` points to the empty `$arr` before the `foreach` starts, In `foreach` it saves the value of `$key` into the `$arr` by reference which was pointed by `$curr` and then reassigns the reference of the newly saved `$key` in `$arr` to the `$curr` pointer again.

```
// initialize variables
$val = 'it works !';
$arr = [];

// Get the keys we want to assign
$keys = [ 'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'key_4' ];

// Get a reference to where we start
echo "create a space where to save the first key \r\n";
$curr = &$arr;

// Loops over keys
$i = 1;
foreach($keys as $key) {

    echo "**************** Iteration no $i ******************\r\n";
    // echo "save the value \"$key\" to the reference created earlier in the \$curr variable for the empty array above where the kesy are actually being saved \r\n";

    // get the reference for this key
    echo "Now save the value of \$key to the array reference present in \$curr and then assigne the reference of newly saved array item to \$curr again \r\n";
    $curr = &$curr[$key];
    print_r($arr);

   $i++;
   echo "\r\n\r\n";
}

// Assign the value to our last reference
$curr = $val;

// visualize the output, so we know its right
print_r($arr);
```