# PHP How to append recursively the next element of the array to the parent

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

The main idea is that I want to convert this array:

```
$arr1 = ['user', 'address', 'street'];
```

To this one:

```
$arr2['user']['address']['street'];
```

I've been trying with recursive functions, foreach, for... but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Example:

```
function appendingArrays($arrayOfKeys, $value) {
    // TODO
}
$finalArray = appendingArrays(['user', 'address', 'street'], 'Lombard Street');

echo $finalArray['user']['address']['street']; // Lombard Street
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519108/split-a-string-to-form-multidimensional-array-keys, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103719/php-make-a-multidimensional-associative-array-from-key-names-in-a-string-separat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356391/php-explode-string-key-into-multidimensional-array-with-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps :
[Go Through Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc6ae479deadc732366f3c1b1de0efadfda28a53)

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

$arr1 = ['user', 'address', 'street'];

$c = count($arr1) - 1;
$out = array();
for($i = $c; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    $out = array($arr1[$i] => $out);
}

/* input */  
print_r($arr1);

/* output */
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => user
    [1] => address
    [2] => street
)
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [street] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```